# ng-app, ng-repeat, ng controller, etc ... what are they from an HTML DOM angle and how can JS access them?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

The following snippet is an excerpt taken from Angular documentation:

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
...
...
```

ng-app ng-controller ng-repeat are referred as directives.

From a DOM angle what are they ? 
how does a javascript snippet can access them in a cross-browser way (which is I guess what angular.js must be doing) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From a DOM angle what are they

They are just normal DOM attributes

> how does a javascript snippet can access them in a cross-browser way

You could access using `getAttribute`, or if you're using jQuery, you could access it by [$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("ng-app"));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQzGP/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @KhanhTO:

When the DOM is parsed by the browser, the angular directives are ignored. To make valid HTML, you can also use the form `data-ng-<name>`.  For example, `np-app` becomes `data-ng-app`.

Angular has a parse cycle of its own after the DOM and js is loaded.  Angular referes to this as its `$compile` phase.  Angular looks through the DOM and identifies its directives during this phase.

> Angular modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event
>   processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and Angular
>   execution context. Only operations which are applied in Angular
>   execution context will benefit from Angular data-binding, exception
>   handling, property watching, etc...

More  in the [conceptual overview](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) of angular.